# inheritance in java is not detecting extended class from other package, of same name

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, methods, extends

I am using Eclipse.

2 folders: src/test  and src/main

Both have a package with same name: `Academy`.

The `Academy` package in **src/test** has in it a class name: **Base.java**

The `Academy` package in **src/main** has in it a class name: **HomePage.java**

In the **HomePage.java** class, `extends Base` is not detecting base class in it.
This is the code inside **HomePage.java**

---

```
package Academy;

import Academy.Base;

public class HomePage extends Base{
}
```

---

There is a red line on `Academy.Base` and on `Base`. It tells to make `Base` class, but it is already there. I tried to save the file. I tried to make new project too. Please Help. Thank you.

Here is the reference image:

[image: refImage]

Comment: Test code is not to be used in source code.

Comment: @pringi    It’s just 2 packages with same name, inside 2 different folders. whether it’s test or not, it should still inherit wth extends. So, how to resolve this? Please suggest. Please refer to image I attached.

Comment: Your package structure is looks to be messed up. If the code is in the same project, why not make the package root the same?

Comment: Can you update your question to show **Base,java** as well?

Comment: @skomisa - While I agree that it would have been good if the OP had done that, the contents of Base.java are not the real issue here.  The real cause of the problem is clear from the posted image.

Comment: try to understand what people are saying, especially @StephenC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved the above error by following these steps:**

Right click on project->Build path->Configure build path->source tab

then search tab search under your project src/main/java

and change "contains test sources" from No to Yes
and apply the changes

Comment: This is a very bad solution. Just move Base into src/main/java.

Comment: she does not have to do that since hse is using maven, by doing that i could be OK with eclispe, but having problems with other ide or building tools on ci

Answer (score 3):

You are using Maven as the build system for your Eclipse project.

Maven does not allow a class in your main tree to depend on a class in the test tree.  It prevents this by telling the Java compiler and runtime that classes and resources in the test tree are not in the build time and runtime classpaths for the main code.  That is why you are getting the compilation error.

Solution:

Move the `Base.java` class into "src/main/java/Academy" directory.

---

You commented:

> It's just 2 packages with same name, inside 2 different folders. whether it's test or not, it should still inherit with extends.

Sorry ... but you are wrong.  It **does** matter which tree you put the classes in.  This is a Maven project, and Maven is "opinionated" about these things.  For good reason, IMO.  But either way, Maven's opinion takes precedence ... if you choose to use Maven.

---

There are a couple of other problems:

1. A package name should start with a lowercase letter.  Read [this](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.1-package-names) for example.

   Solution: Rename `Academy` to `academy`<sup>1</sup>.
2. Non-code resources should not be in a "java" directory.  Non-code resources in a "java" source directory won't be on the runtime classpath ... and won't be included in (regular) JAR files.

   Solution: Create a "resources" directory and put it there.
3. The `import Academy.Base;` is redundant.  It is not necessary to import a class in the same package.

---

<sup>1 - Alternate solution: don't ask other people to work on your code, or help you with it.  If other people don't **ever** need to read your code, it only matters to you what your code looks like.  The compiler doesn't care.  Only humans do.</sup>

Comment: To be precise, nothing here is done by Maven, it's Eclipse following Maven's concept that test code and libraries (shown darker) are not visible/accessible from within main code.

Comment: Well ... yea ... but you will get exactly the same behavior if you do a Maven build in Eclipse, or if you do a Maven build of the project from the command line.  Indeed, if Eclipse *didn't* follow Maven's concept then the Eclipse Maven plugin would be unusable.

Comment: Yes, in contrast to resolving and downloading dependencies, Maven code cannot be used here because Maven cannot compile incrementally nor does it provide concepts for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` was irrelevant.

Your src/main/java/, src/main/resources/ are packed for your main product, probably something like E2EProject1.jar.

Your src/test/java/, src/test/resources/ are packed in your unit tests, probably something like E2EProject1-test.jar. These test classes are kept outside your main product, but have the main product on the class path as dependency.

So it should be something like:

- src/main/java/Base.java
- src/test/resources/data.properties (or src/main/resources/)

That the packages are named identical is for being able to test (implicitly import) non-public, package private classes of src/main/java in unit test classes in src/test/java.